# How to calculate amountOutMin parameter in the UniswapV3 swapRouter.exactInputSingle() function using an onchain oracle?

Tags: solidity, uniswap, swaps, uniswapv3

Can someone tell me how to calculate the `amountOutMin` parameter in the `swapRouter.exactInputSingle()` function using an onchain oracle? I've got a working uniswapV3 oracle that can retrieve the price of a token and my V3 swap function works as expected. We can easily change the oracle implementation to retreive two prices if needed. I've included some of the code below - see TODO

```
    function swapExactInputSingle(
        address _tokenIn,
        address _tokenOut,
        uint256 _amountIn
    ) private returns (uint256 amountOut) {
        TransferHelper.safeApprove(_tokenIn, address(swapRouter), _amountIn);

        uint32 secondsIn = 10;
        uint256 price = IUniswapV3PriceOracle(uniswapV3PriceOracle).estimateAmountOut(_tokenIn, uint128(_amountIn), secondsIn);

        // TODO: We need to use the price from the oracle to calculate amountOutMinimum
        uint256 amountOutMinimum = 1;

        ISwapRouter.ExactInputSingleParams memory params = ISwapRouter
            .ExactInputSingleParams({
                tokenIn: _tokenIn,
                tokenOut: _tokenOut,
                fee: poolFee,
                recipient: address(this),
                deadline: block.timestamp,
                amountIn: _amountIn,
                amountOutMinimum: amountOutMinimum,
                sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0
            });

        amountOut = swapRouter.exactInputSingle(params);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please share the code for the oracle you're using? I guess it is a TWAP oracle and I'm curious about the TWAP duration you're using in production. Did you use a 10s TWAP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet that you need to change:

```
amountOutMinimum: amountOutMinimum,
```

for

```
amountOutMinimum: price,
```

Comment: Yeah turns out the price from the price oracle was all I needed. For some reason I thought it may be complicated than that - thanks.

I later calculated what 99% of the price would be and passed that into `amountOutMin` - this meant I allowed for 1% slippage.